# Validating model choice in glmmadmb

Tags: mixed-model, glmm, overfitting, count-data

I have a small dataset of count data that has a number of zero measurements. My overdispersion is fairly large. Due to this, I was drawn to using the `glmmadmb` package.

I understand how to compare the fit of the distributions (poisson, nbinom etc) using AICtab.

What I am struggling with is how to assess whether the model with the 'best' fit of distribution actually fits my data. On 'normal' glm's, this is where you would use

```r
qqnorm(resid(model))
qqline(resid(model))
```

I am aware, however, that the assumptions required to use this are not met in negative binomials etc etc.

Therefore, I am wondering if someone would point me in the right direction of finding an answer.... how would you validate your model choice in GLMMADMB?

Many thanks in advance for your help, I really appreciate your time and efforts.

**EDIT**: 8th May 2014

My data set is a very very simple one ….. I am testing a behaviour response to an audio playback stimuli. I have 10 animals that are played a control playback, and the same 10 animals played a treatment playback the following day (alternated to balance treatment order effects). Therefore, I have only one fixed effect (Audio Treatment) and one random effect (Individual Name). I feel that I am comfortable with `lmer` functions and have used `lme4` on several, much larger models, of both count and binomial. I am a little unsure of my understanding of `glmmadmb` models…. What I see the issue as being with this small model, is that 5 / 10 of the measured responses for control playback are 0 (with the other 5 / 10 being small numbers, and 10 / 10 to treatment playback being large numbers).

My dataset looks as follows:

```r
Individual  Audio_Treatment Behaviour
A   TREATMENT   60
B   TREATMENT   29
C   TREATMENT   32
D   TREATMENT   40
E   TREATMENT   3
F   TREATMENT   25
G   TREATMENT   21
H   TREATMENT   50
I   TREATMENT   11
J   TREATMENT   43
A   CONTROL     4
B   CONTROL     0
C   CONTROL     0
D   CONTROL     0
E   CONTROL     19
F   CONTROL     10
G   CONTROL     4
H   CONTROL     0
I   CONTROL     0
J   CONTROL     3
```

And I have fitted the following model:

```r
 modelNBIT <- glmmadmb(BEHAVIOUR ~ AUDIO_TREATMENT + (1|INDIVIDUAL), 
       family="nbinom1", zeroInflation = TRUE)

I had initially thought that truncated models (or hurdle models) might be more suited to this, however the truncated `glmmadmb` runs the following error ... (perhaps due to overfitting)

    Parameters were estimated, but not standard errors were not:
     the most likely problem is that the curvature at MLE was zero or negative

Going back to my original question – I was wondering if someone would be able to suggest a way to validate the model (in this precise case, modelNBIT)?
```

Comment: I would consider *posterior predictive simulation* for goodness of fit -- that is, simulate new data from your fitted model, compute some summary statistic you're interested in (e.g. number of non-zero values, or mean of non-zero values, or something) and see how well it does. `glmmADMB` doesn't have a `simulate` method, which makes things a little harder. Can you say a little more about your model? Do you have random effects?

Comment: @ Ben Bolker, Thank you very much for your expertise, I really appreciate it. I will edit my original post to include more details.